# What does "storage-class information" mean in __declspec()?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, declspec

I am reading the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) about __declspec.

It starts with:

> The extended attribute syntax for specifying ***storage-class information***
>   uses the __declspec keyword, which specifies that an instance of a
>   given type is to be stored with a Microsoft-specific storage-class
>   attribute listed below. ...

What exactly does ***storage-class information*** mean? And how does it affect the compiler?

### ADD 1

Someone posted a link as comment but deleted it soon after. I found the link useful. So I add it here.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: While the link to "storage duration" describes some loosely common concepts with what is described in MSDN article, this is still purely coincidental. Storage duration is a formal language-level concept. The MSDN article is about completely unrelated non-standard compiler extension. The only common point I see is `thread_local` storage duration and `__declspec(thread)` in MSDN article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the article uses the terms "extended attribute" and "storage-class attribute" interchangeably. These terms simply refer to the attributes that you can specify inside `__declspec(...)`.

Each attribute has its own meaning and they are mostly unrelated to each other. You can follow the links from the article to read about what each attribute does.